# Silverlight/VB 6 Integration

Tags: silverlight, vb6

VB 6 can host web pages, which means it can also host Silverlight apps.

Communication from VB 6 to Silverlight can easily be done via URLs. But is there a way for the Silverlight app to send messages back to VB 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok how about this then.. Within the SilverLight app use the `HtmlPage` class to update the title of the page this can be monitored from the `WebBrowser_TitleChange` event in vb.

Silverlight code :-

```
var document = HtmlPage.Document;
document.SetProperty("title","whatever you need");
```

VB6 code :-

```
Private Sub WebBrowser_TitleChange(ByVal Text As String)        
    Debug.Print "Title changed to : " & Text        
End Sub
```

You'd have to ignore the initial TitleChange event when the page loads.

Comment: You win the prize sir. It's a bit hacky, but it will certainly do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `Winsock` control to the vb app and get silverlight to talk back to it using `WebClient`?

Comment: Last I heard Silverlight cannot talk to other apps on the user's machine. I would have to bouce it back through the web server.

Comment: Ok yeah I was working locally with the silverlight app & vb and (wrongly) assumed it would all be on a local network. Back to the drawing board...